# Prove the trigonometric identity: $(\cos^3 x - \sin^3 x) / (\cos x - \sin x) = (2 + \sin 2x) / 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$\frac{\cos^3 x - \sin^3 x}{\cos x - \sin x }= \frac{1}{2}\left( 2 + \sin 2x \right)$$

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE. Thank you for your question! It is good practice on this site to add a bit of information on the context your question came up in, and to share your own work on it. It's also fine if you state that you're completely lost -- the information is helpful for answerers to gauge their answer on. For more information on asking a good question on this site, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959/43351).

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

$$\frac{a^3-b^3}{a-b}=\frac{(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}{a-b}=a^2+b^2+ab\ldots$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\cos^{3}x-\sin^{3}x=(\cos x-\sin x)(\cos^2x+\sin x \cos x+\sin^2x)$$

Recall that $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$ and $\sin 2x=2\sin x \cos x$ . Then 
$$\cos^{3}x-\sin^{3}x=(\cos x-\sin x)(1+\frac{\sin 2x}{2})$$

So
$$\frac{\cos^{3}x-\sin^{3}x}{\cos x-\sin x}=\frac{(\cos x-\sin x)(1+\frac{\sin 2x}{2})}{\cos x-\sin x}=\frac{2+\sin2x}{2}$$